# How to use the gem 'paperclip' with nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, paperclip, nested-forms

In Devise's edit page, I'm placing image uploader with using paperclip.
If I try to put image_tag here, it gives error back like this.

```
NoMethodError in Registrations#edit 
undefined method `photo' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x000000210752d0>
```

I have 'User' model, which is used by Devise.
and User has one 'UserProfile' model.
In 'UserProfile', I added :photo to attr_accessible.
I also added this to 'UserProfile' model in order to use paperclip

```
  has_attached_file :photo,
    :styles => {
    :thumb=> "100x100>",
    :small  => "400x400>" }
```

My edit view is

```
<% resource.build_user_profile if resource.user_profile.nil? %>
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

    <%= f.fields_for :user_profile do |profile_form| %>

      <div><%= profile_form.label :nickname %><br /> 
      <%= profile_form.text_field :nickname %></div> 

      <div><%= profile_form.label :photo %><br /> 
      <%= profile_form.file_field :photo %></div>

     <% if profile_form.photo.exists? then %>
      <%= image_tag profile_form.photo.url %>
      <%= image_tag profile_form.photo.url(:thumb) %>
      <%= image_tag profile_form.photo.url(:small) %>
     <% end %>
   <% end %> 

...continue on
```

Answer (score 0):

Try actually assigning the newly built user_profile to a variable:

```
<% user_profile = resource.build_user_profile if resource.user_profile.nil? %>
```

and then passing that variable to the fields_for like this:

```
<%= f.fields_for user_profile do |profile_form| %>
```

or

```
<%= f.fields_for :user_profile, user_profile do |profile_form| %>
```

I believe that should work?

Answer (score 0):

To make a nested form, in your parent model (User), add this

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos
```

This allows you to pass and params related to Photo model and user in one go. Rails makes a special hash key which stores the values of photo model with the name :

```
photos_attributes
```

Now, when you do @user = User.new params[:user], it also builds the @user.photos

Also, In your User controller new method, add:
@user.photo.build

Refer to this awesome railscast by ryan bates for full explanation:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip

And this also might be useful:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html